# I am using devise and cancan gems. When I sign_in I get redirect back to sign_in page

Tags: devise, cancan

Here is the log

```
    Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-02 09:57:19 -0400
    Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"abc=", "user"=>{"email"=>"xyz@abc.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
    User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'xyz@abc.com' LIMIT 1
    Completed 401 Unauthorized in 9ms
    Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xyz=", "user"=>{"email"=>"xyz@abc.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
    Rendered /Users/nitsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.1.3/app/views/devise/shared/_links.erb (0.6ms)
    Rendered /Users/nitsingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/devise-2.1.3/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
```

Comment: clearly showing usrename/password miss match **Completed 401 Unauthorized in 9ms**

Comment: Have you made sure that the user exists, and that the login information is correct? Which versions of Rails, devise and Cancan are you using?